# Late 1950s sci fi movie where two pilots tested out an experimental military jet and landed on another planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie in about 1957 or '58 which began with two pilots who were testing some sort of experimental military jet.  They went so fast and so high that when they landed, it turned out that they were on another planet.  I don't remember what happened to them but it would be fun to see it again.

The film was in color.

Answer (score 5):

Could you be thinking of the 1960 film, *[Beyond the Time Barrier](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053651/?ref_=tt_urv)*? It's the future, and involves a single test pilot, but has a similar premise:

> Experimental pilot testing a new rocket powered craft (actually a Convair F-102 interceptor) manages to fly into the future and land at the now deserted airbase he left. He ends up in a city with people who are suspicious he is a spy and who want to keep him to procreate with the rulers daughter because the majority of the inhabitants are sterile. He manages to escape and return to his own time but "with consequences".

Said consequences, as best I can tell from a plot summary, are that:

> The pilot is shown at the end of the film to have rapidly aged to decrepitude as a result of his time travel.

### Trailer

It's also in black-and-white, which you did not mention, but would fit with the era you believe the film to be in.

Found with search terms of *1950s film "experimental jet" lands on a different planet*

Comment: sigh... Google-fu is an obscure art... Knowing what terms to search for, I mean

Comment: And since search results are tailored, the same search terms might come up with different results.

Comment: Do ya know what? I remember watching that in the cinema about 1974/75. There was a sci fi weekend and that was one!

Comment: @DannyMcG What the "consequences" were? I've posted my best guess for what they were referring to.

Comment: Was this based on a book does anybody know?....I remember reading a paperback once and going "But - but - it's that film I once watched about an experimental plane"

Comment: Is this where I post a response to an answer?  My response is:  Thanks for your answer but "Beyond the Time Barrier" doesn't sound right.  I'm sure I remember that the film I saw was in color and I'm pretty sure that there were two pilots.  But I should try to watch "Beyond the Time Barrier" anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: @RichardSamuelson: This is a fine place to make such comments. :) I've added the detail that the film was in color to your question. By the by, have people referred you to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to elicit further details?